# Is virtual table used when calling virtual functions on statically allocated objects

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here's an example:

```
struct A {
  virtual int f() const { return 1; }
};

struct B : A {
  virtual int f() const { return 2; }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  cout << b.f() << endl;
}
```

Is there going to be a virtual table lookup incurred to call `f()` on the instance of `B`, or not? Or is it possible, but compilers can optimize it out?

Comment: For polymorphism to work you need a pointer or reference to a base class. In your case there is no need for a virtual table lookup, and the compiler is free to optimize it out.

Comment: Since the C++ standard does not specify a "virtual table lookup", it's hard to answer this question from the point of view of the C++ program you're showing. This may be better suited as a question to a compiler vendor about a particular compiler.

Comment: None of the above, because `B::f` is private. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the compiler and optimization options.

But as  a rule, when a modern compiler knows the most derived type of an object, it will optimize away (the indirection of) direct virtual calls on the objects.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks, I meant to write "most derived". Sorry. This is a term defined by the standard, in C+11 §1.8/4.